# Not a member error when C++ winrt Page Class used along with XAML page

Tags: c++, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I'm building a simple ActionTracker program. I have a very simple XAML file:

//XAML file

```
 <Page
    x:Class="ActionTracker_V3.ActionDetails"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ActionTracker_V3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind temp, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The backing runtime class is defined as:

//IDL file

```
namespace ActionTracker_V3
{
runtimeclass ActionDetails : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
{
    ActionDetails();
    String temp;
}
 }
```

The associated *.h file and *.cpp files are shown below:

```
#include "ActionDetails.g.h"

namespace winrt::ActionTracker_V3::implementation
{
struct ActionDetails : ActionDetailsT<ActionDetails>
{
    ActionDetails();

    hstring temp();
    void temp(hstring const& value);
};
}

namespace winrt::ActionTracker_V3::factory_implementation
{
   struct ActionDetails : ActionDetailsT<ActionDetails,    implementation::ActionDetails>
{};
}
```

The *.cpp file is:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "ActionDetails.h"

 namespace winrt::ActionTracker_V3::implementation
 {
ActionDetails::ActionDetails() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

hstring ActionDetails::temp()
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}

void ActionDetails::temp(hstring const& value)
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}
}
```

However, when I compile these files I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2039   'ActionDetails': is not a member  of 'winrt::ActionTracker_V3::implementation'  ActionTracker_V3    c:\users\kurian.kattukaren\source\repos\actiontracker_v3\actiontracker_v3\generated files\xamltypeinfo.g.cpp
```

I don't know what's causing the error. I could not find anything wrong in the class declaration. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I didn't reproduce this issue. While adding a new ActionDetails.xaml page with the code your provided, I only get not implement exception. Can you try add a new project from project template and make sure it runs without problem first? Then add a new ActionDetail page. I would guess some other things are affecting your issue.

Comment: Barry, It works when I created a new project and then add an ActionDetail Page. Thank you very much. However, I still could not point out why it was giving me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the troubleshooting steps listed on [Troubleshooting C++/WinRT issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/troubleshooting#:%7E:text=The%20C%2B%2B%20compiler%20produces%20the%20error%20%22%27implements_type%27%3A%20is%20not%20a%20member%20of%20any%20direct%20or%20indirect%20base%20class%20of%20%27%3Cprojected%20type%3E%27%22.) (slightly reformatted):

> > The C++ compiler produces the error "'implements_type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of ''".
>
> This can happen when you call **make** with the namespace-unqualified name of your implementation type (**MyRuntimeClass**, for example), and you haven't included that type's header. The compiler interprets **MyRuntimeClass** as the projected type.
>
> The solution is to include the header for your implementation type (`MyRuntimeClass.h`, for example).

I copied the above info just want to say that your problem may due to the compiler cannot find the right header from your project. But that does not mean your code has any problem. It is possible that some settings are not correct, or it is just Visual Studio's problem. Without your project I can also not be sure. If this always happen in your environment and you are sure your code is correct, please report it directly from Visual Studio->About->Send feedback to Developer Community forum.

Anyway, any time if you have a strange error from your project, you can try a new project as a test first.